# Bluetooth Low Energy App

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid, proximity, rssi

I am new to android development,
I am trying to make an app that gives me the UUID, RSSI, Major, Minor values of all the BLE devices available nearby. I want my app to give notifications too when I enter a particular BLE region along with the proximity level of that device and keep on scanning for devices after particular intervals and keep on updating the proximity and rssi values. I want to do this by using the functions available in android sdk only (don't want to import any external libraries with in built functions for the same). Kidly tell me which functions to use and how to proceed on this.
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by "proximity", you may find it difficult or impossible to accomplish.  See this [excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687332/bluetooth-le-rssi-for-proximity-detection-ios) on iOS RSSI proximity for more information.  To summarize, RSSI is in general to imprecise and incapable of providing precise measurements.  The RSSI level may say more about a devices orientation than its position in space.  More abstract or imprecise proximity information may be doable.

In regards to your requirements for an app, the [Android Sample App](http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html) is a good starting place for any Android BLE developer and demonstrates most of the functionality your looking for.  The Android Developers [BLE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) page, while incomplete, is also useful; as are [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870189/android-4-3-bluetooth-low-energy-unstable) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069507/solved-gatt-callback-fails-to-register) posts if you run in to trouble.

Comment: By proximity i mean the distance to the BLE peripheral from  the phone.
I am a newbie to android development, I tried the things mentioned on developer.android.com but i get confused on as how to get my major and minor values on the phone.
I would be very thankful if you can guide me through this.