# Converting RSSI BLE values to something more meaningful on IOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know that BLE RSSI values are based on decibel values but I was wondering if there was a way to convert this into a more meaningful value that I could use (even a float would be fine).

I've looked at Kalmon filters but I'm struggling to understand them. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705647/finding-distance-from-rssi-value-of-bluetooth-low-energy-enable-device

Answer (score 0):

With the limitations of the iphones and ipads' hardware I dont believe there is a method for getting more precise data from RSSI values. Perhaps if you say what you are using it for I can  help advise an alternative route to solve your problem.  I understand that it is difficult to gain qualitative information from RSSI values from Bluetooth LE, however, there are also other methods such as coupling different systems with Bluetooth LE that may produce the data you are seeking.