# Objective-C iOS 6 BLE (Bluetooth 4.0) Distance calculation

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to calculate the distance between the device and the iPhone, or at least, have an idea of the strength so I can check if the distance is getting smaller or bigger as I move. I would like to build some sort of system which makes it easier to find "lost" things in a close perimeter.

Is such thing possible? And if so, what is the best way to do this.

I assume that there is no obstruction between the two devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely!

Actually it's basic functionality provided by Core Bluetooth. To reference a [link](http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/39707371281/core-bluetooth-for-ios-6-core-bluetooth-was) provided by a previous answer:

> As soon as a Peripheral is discovered during the scanning, the Central
>   delegate receives the following callback:
>
> - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
>     advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber
>     *)RSSI
>
> This call notifies the Central Manager delegate (the view controller)
>   that a peripheral with advertisement data and RSSI was discovered.
>   RSSI stands for Received Signal Strength Indicator. This is a cool
>   parameter, because knowing the strength of the transmitting signal and
>   the RSSI, you can estimate the current distance between the Central
>   and the Peripheral. So, you can use the distance as a filter for a
>   given service: only if the Central is close enough to the Peripheral,
>   then your app does something.

The RSSI value allows you to estimate the distance, create virtual fences and can also be used to zero-in on a BLE device by comparing the new RSSI measurement to the previous one.

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I meant, I don't need to have a real calculation of the distance, just knowing if I'm getting colder or hotter :).

Comment: Ok, my mistake : I provided same link, but didn't take the time to read it thoroughly. Other SI question about that here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705647/finding-distance-from-rssi-value-of-bluetooth-low-energy-enable-device

Comment: Anyway, little update, I figured out a way to roughly tell a person he is getting closer or farther from the object. It's a very rough estimate but it's better than no information at all when searching for something. Since the RSSI is so unstable, you might want to use a floating/moving average of the last 50 RSSIs and compare it to the last 5 RSSIs. (the amounts are just examples, with some tweaking you'll get there). And also allow a small margin of error of a few percent so your scanner isn't to sensitive.

Comment: We could use this before the ble device is connected to iPhone. What if i need to show the distance once the device is connected to iPhone ?

Comment: did anyone get the distance between the BLE device and peripheral using RSSI ? anyone ? if yes then guide me with this .