# Measuring proximity with bluetooth on raspberry Pi

Tags: python, sockets, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I've been trying to use this script https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/examples/advanced/inquiry-with-rssi.py but it seems that `sock = bluez.hci_open_dev(dev_id)` returns a non-working socket.  Every time sock is passed into a function `error(9, 'Bad file descriptor')` is thrown.

This script is pretty old so there is a decent chance it doesn't work any more.  So I have two questions.  Does anyone know how to use the pybluez library (or a more modern equivalent) to measure proximity of a bluetooth device with a raspberry pi?

And what am I doing wrong with this script that is causing me to build a broken socket?

Thanks.

Comment: the link to your script is broken, potentially the same thing: https://pybluez.googlecode.com/svn-history/r1/trunk/examples/advanced/inquiry-with-rssi.py

Comment: It's been a while now but I believe that is the same script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Run `hcitool dev` to get the address of your bluetooth device.

In the script you linked to, change line 120 from:

```
dev_id = 0
```

to:

```
dev_id = bluez.hci_get_route(ADDRESS_FOR_YOUR_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE)
```

To measure proximity, the script calls the function

```
device_inquiry_with_with_rssi(sock)
```

which should print a list of bluetooth device ids and their corresponding RSSI values (see lines 95-102). Typically, devices must be in pairing mode to show up in the inquiry results. The function also returns the list of IDs/RSSIs as an array, so you can call it from your own code and process the returned results.  The RSSI value indicates the signal strength of a device, and so is an indirect measure of proximity (see [Finding distance from RSSI value of Bluetooth Low Energy enabled device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705647/finding-distance-from-rssi-value-of-bluetooth-low-energy-enable-device) ).

Comment: This seems to me on the right track but NULL is not the null singleton in python and None doesn't work.  The hci_get_route function wants a stringified address of your receiving bluetooth device.  This can be obtained by running hcitool dev in your terminal

Comment: Sorry about that; I've revised the answer.  Instead of NULL, -1

Comment: I think dev_id = bluez.hci_get_route() may also work.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the device you want to use, Bluepy in Python might be a better method. I used a Pi3 to measure RSSI from Bluetooth modules (HM-10, CC254x-based devices) and was able to get reasonable estimates of distance. There's a ton of noise in RSSI, so expect inaccuracies of no less than 1m with some signal processing. I wrote a blog post on RSSI from HM-10 and Rpi, check it out for a more in-depth method of how I do it. I even included some Python code:

https://engineersportal.com/blog/2017/12/31/using-raspberry-pi-hm-10-and-bluepy-to-develop-an-ibeacon-mesh-network-part-1