# python - bluetooth device proximity

Tags: python, bluetooth

I have a simple question. Is there a way how to detect proximity between 2 BT devices in python?

I have a notebook (BT 4.0) and my phone (BT 4.0) and I wanna know, how far the phone from notebook is. I know this measurement can be done based on signal strenght. The thing is I wasn't able to find a library (i.e. PyBluez) to be able to show signal strenght.

On the other hand on Google Play there is dozen apps which measure signal strenght.

Is there something I'm not able to google?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the [python-bluetooth-scanner](https://code.google.com/p/python-bluetooth-scanner/)?

Comment: Also, [possibly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22443896/measuring-proximity-with-bluetooth-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: The first library doesn't measure signal strength and the second example is outdated. I've tried both of them.

Comment: What do you mean by the second example being outdated? PyBluez has support for Python 2 as well as 3.