# Find Distance using iBeacon in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I am developing a app for Bluetooth device.

I used iBeacon feature for indoor location, but can't find indoor location, it return only region.

I have a current location. But now I want to find distance between current location to iBeacon location. I searched a lot. But didn't get any proper solution.

From my search I get to know that I can find distance from RSSI.

But my question is how can I find location or distance with that property.

Comment: do you want to find location in longitude latitude of iBeacon, or range in meters for example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding distance from RSSI value of Bluetooth Low Energy enabled device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705647/finding-distance-from-rssi-value-of-bluetooth-low-energy-enabled-device)

Comment: If we can find in latitude and longitude than good. If it returns in meter than how can i convert it to latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't find current position (in longitude latitude) by using 1 iBeacon, But if you want to find distance (for example beacon is in range of 5 meters) than look [this](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ijitee.org%2Fattachments%2FFile%2Fv2i2%2FA0359112112.pdf&ei=8rdCUoPANo6R0QXn_4GYDA&usg=AFQjCNFjrPoiVn7e9xPV1mi55AS4E6jwpg&bvm=bv.53077864,d.d2k) document. The formula is #19 on page 3 and basically it is this:

```
Received Signal Strength is related to distance using the
equation below.
RSSI [dBm] = -10n log10 (d) + A [dBm]
```

Where
**A** *is the received signal strength in dBm at 1 meter - you need to calibrate this on your system. Because you are calibrating at a known distance you don't need to take into account the frequency of your transmission and this simplifies the equation. (Just place the iBeacon to 1 meters range, and measure it's RSSI)*

**n** is *the propagation pathloss exponent i.e. 2.7 to 4.3 (Free space has n = 2 for reference, if there are walls it will be greater).*

**d** *is the distance from the sender in meters*

So you have all values, except **d**, you need to calculate **d** by using mentioned formula.

BTW, if you want to get position of beacon, you need to triangulate it (by using more than 3 beacons) [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332856/triangulate-example-for-ibeacons)

Comment: Thanks for understanding my question.. I ll accept very soon.

Comment: Plus 1 for Nice Explanation.. I ll accept it very soon.

Comment: did anyone get the distance between the BLE device using RSSI ? if yes then guide me how to find it .

Answer (score 0):

CLBeacon class has a property named accuracy for it.  [Apple Developer Site Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLBeacon_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLBeacon/accuracy)

Comment: just use google translate, and translate "accuracy" word to your native language ;)