# How to show local notification on iWatch when iPhone disconnected?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, swift5

How to show local notification in iWatch when iPhone disconnected  with iWatch ? any methods that continuously check iWatch reachability or called when watch reachability status change? I want to show local notification in iWatch

e.g whenever watch connected or disconnected it's show location notification on iWatch.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: you don't have to do anything see answer has already been posted....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In iWatch show local notification when iPhone ( e.g 10 meters) away from iWatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283630/in-iwatch-show-local-notification-when-iphone-e-g-10-meters-away-from-iwatch)

Answer (score 3):

When your iWatch is connected to your iPhone. If your iPhone screen is lock then notification will be passed to iWatch. You don't have to do anything to pass it to iWatch you can see the Apple documentation for more clarification.

[Check this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html)

Comment: I want exactly like whenever watch connected or disconnected it's show location notification on iWatch.